# SELECT COUNT if one of them fulfills condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I have a table with: Country Varchar(20), City Varchar(20), Street Varchar(20)

I want to count the streets of all cities IF one of them is Main Street

It should be something like this...

```
SELECT Country, City, Count(Street)
FROM Streets
GROUP BY Country, City;
```

I don't know how to check if one of the street names is Main Street what should I do?

Comment: please tag your RDBMS, as dialects differ and some solutions like posted one may not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
SELECT Country, City, Count(Street)
FROM Streets
GROUP BY Country, City
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Street = 'Main Street' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0;
```

Comment: I'm getting an error in the final ;

I'm using SQL Developer

Comment: For SQL Server, add `> 0` before the final `;`

Comment: `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Street = 'Main Street' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` is an invalid condition. Did you forget the `> ...`?

Comment: For some databases (like SQLite3), it works even without `> 0` as any non-zero value is considered true.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply go with this.

```
SELECT Country, City, Count(Street) FROM Streets where upper(streets)='MAIN STREET' GROUP BY Country, City;
```

Comment: Not really.  Your count will not reflect the total number of streets for that city.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery in the WHERE clause to find all the cities which have a Main Street:

```
SELECT COUNTRY, CITY, COUNT(STREETS)
  FROM STREETS
  WHERE (COUNTRY, CITY) IN (SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY, CITY
                              FROM STREETS
                              WHERE UPPER(STREET) = 'MAIN STREET')
  GROUP BY COUNTRY, CITY
```

or you can use a join

```
SELECT s.COUNTRY, s.CITY, COUNT(s.STREETS)
  FROM STREETS s
  INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY, CITY
                FROM STREETS
                WHERE LOWER(STREET) = 'main street') c
    ON c.COUNTRY = s.COUNTRY AND
       c.CITY = s.CITY
```

or you can use a Common Table Expression:

```
WITH cteCITIES_WITH_MAIN_STREET AS (SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY, CITY
                                      FROM STREETS
                                      WHERE INITCAP(STREET) = 'Main Street')
SELECT s.COUNTRY, s.CITY, COUNT(s.STREETS)
  FROM STREETS s
  INNER JOIN cteCITIES_WITH_MAIN_STREET c
    ON c.COUNTRY = s.COUNTRY AND
       c.CITY = s.CITY
```

Note: not tested on animals; you'll be first! :-)

Best of luck.